# Why is my JavaScript hash with the reserved word "toString" as a key showing NaN?

Tags: javascript

I am doing a programming exercise that wants me to count all the occurrences of a word within a string, like "the dog went to the other dog".

I have to return a hash with the counts like so for the example above: {the: 2, dog: 2, went: 1, to: 1, other: 1}

But my question is how do I deal with counting reserved words, I am getting NaN.

So this string {"the dog went to the other dog toString"}, returns this for me:

{the: 2, dog: 2, went: 1, to: 1, other: 1, toString: NaN}

How can I get this to give me the real count and not NaN.

Comment: what algorithm are you using?

Comment: write us your function processing this calculation please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript actually does not have hashes.  So if you are creating a hash like this: `hash = {}` then you are actually creating an object with already existing properties in its prototype chain. This includes the `toString` function. To avoid this, create an object with `Object.create(null)` to store your word counts.

Here is an example:

```
 var words = function(string) { 
 var words_array = string.split(" "); 
 var word_count_hash = Object.create(null); 

 words_array.map( function (word){
   if (word in word_count_hash)
     word_count_hash[word] ++; 
   else word_count_hash[word] = 1;
  }); 

  return word_count_hash;
  }
```

Comment: Here is an example:
   var words = function(string) {
  
   var words_array = string.replace.split(" ");

   var word_count_hash = Object.create(null);

   words_array.map( function (word) { if (word in word_count_hash)  word_count_hash[word] ++;
    else word_count_hash[word] = 1;});

    return word_count_hash;

Comment: @Glen It could be nice if you move that example into your answer to make it easier for future readers to get all the content.